# how to give the two categories in AVAudioSession set category

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using the "AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord" category for the audio session. But it didn't plays in silent mode. I need to give "AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback" also. But only one can be given. I need both categories. If any one knows the answer please help me.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple doc - the mode "AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord", should play in silent mode. It sounds like this is the only one you need.
Maybe you missed this note:

> Note: For your app to continue playing audio when the Ring/Silent switch is set to silent and the screen is locked, make sure the UIBackgroundModes audio key has been added to your app’s Info.plist file. This requirement is in addition to your using the correct category.